# change h1 hover color only for links

Tags: css, hyperlink, colors, hover

I'm trying to figure out how to change the hover color, but only when the text has a link

This is the css code, but it changes color with or without links

```
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
color:#3F3F3F;
}

h1:hover, h2:hover, h3:hover, h4:hover {
color:#000000;
}
```

Comment: h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover ....

Comment: This will depend on how you have structured the links.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I tried that but the color hover doesn't work this way, and I don't know why

Comment: @DavidM so you need to also post your markup. Please share a fiddle with your attempts

Answer (score 3):

This will depend on how you have structured the links.

There are two basic varieties.

a) Links inside headings. In which case:

```css
a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="#">Link Inside Heading</a></h1>
```

b) Headings inside links. In which event:

```css
a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
}
a:hover {
  color: green;
}
/* or */

h1 {
  background: #c0ffee;
}
a h1:hover {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><h1>Heading Inside Link</h1></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample:

```
h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover, h4 a:hover {
   color:grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The anwser you are looking for is simple:

```
h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, ect {
    color:#000000;
}
```

You stated that the header when hovered should change color, which is not what you want.
Now it says that a header which contains a link (a) should change color when it is hovered. ;)